# Javascript REGEX matching two brackets [[something]]

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

trying to match anything width and **including** two brackets e.g. `[[match this]]` so I can replace without brackets.

here is what I have as far `var regex = /([\[\|\]])\w+/g;`

However this matches the above like this `[match`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `[\[\|\]]` means any of the characters `[`, `|` or `]`. You need to escape _every_ square bracket. The `\w+` is still outside any bracket and it won’t match whitespace as in the example `[[match this]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `([\[\|\]])\w+` matches 1 symbol - `[`, `|` or `]` (with `([\[\|\]])`) and then 1 or more word (alphanumeric or underscore characters). See [how your regex actually performs](https://regex101.com/r/kC7rF6/1).

Use the following replacement:

```
.replace(/\[\[(.*?)]]/g, "$1")
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ2zJ4/1)

The `/\[\[(.*?)]]/g` will find all non-overlapping occurrences of `[[`, followed with 0+ characters other than a newline (if you need to also match newlines, replace with `[^]*?` or `[\s\S]*?`), and then two literal `]` symbols (note that you do not need to escape them outside the character class in JS patterns).

The `.*?` matches as few any chars other than a newline as possible for the engine to return a valid match, i.e. it matches up to the first occurrence of `]]`. If the match must include everything up to the last occurrence of `]]`, `.*` is enough.

Note that if the substrings inside `[[` / `]]` are very long, I'd rather unroll the whole regex pattern as `/\[\[([^\]]*(?:](?!])[^\]]*)*)]]/g`.

Comment: Why the `*` and the `?` . . . shouldn't the `*` be sufficient?

Comment: I forgot to add: `.*?` matches as few any chars other than a newline as possible for the engine to return a valid match, I.e. it matches up to the first occurrence of `]]`. If the match must include everything up to the last occurrence of `]]`, `.*` is enough.

Comment: Note that if the substrings inside `[[` / `]]` are very long, I'd rather unroll it as `/\[\[([^\]]*(?:](?!])[^\]]*)*)]]/g`.

Comment: Gotchya . . . I see where you were coming from.